# Who is Gaya Avatar of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, yajna

The [Satvata Tantra Part 2 Verse 17](https://archive.org/stream/SriSatvataTantraEnglishTranslation_201804/Sri-Satvata-Tantra-English-Translation#page/n5/mode/1up) mentions:

> Born as Gaya in King Priyavrata's dynasty, the Lord became very famous by the actions of His body, mind and words. Yajna personified, which had the form of Indra, passionately competed with him.

I know Yajna is also an incarnation of Lord Vishnu but I want to know who this Gaya Avatar was?

Comment: It would be good if you can consolidate questions that only change the name of the avatara - otherwise HSE will be flooded with this type of questions @viraj .

Comment: I thought of doing that but then there are people who come up with comments such as your question is too broad limit it to one thing at a time :) Anyhow please share an answer if you know more on this topic.

Comment: Never heard of him before!